# How to fan-out GameObjects

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 3d

**Preinformation**: Using Kinect v2 and Unity3D v5.4

**Background**: I have a parent `GameObject`, which is a 3D model (e.g. a MacBook). This parent `GameObject` is composed of several child `GameObjects`. These child `GameObjects` are the smaller Details of the 3D model (e.g. Display, USB-Port, Keyboard etc.). The MacBook itself can be rotated and scaled. What i want to do is fanning out these child `GameObjects` proportional when using the mousewheel.

**Problem**: How do i implement this fan-out mechanism, independent of the current rotation of the parent `GameObject`.

The image makes it hopefully more clear. The rectangles are representing child `GameObjects`.

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MBrYk.png)

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to just change distance between your parent and childs add this to your child objects:

```
void Update ()
{
    transform.localPosition += (transform.localPosition.normalized * Input.GetAxis("Mouse ScrollWheel") * 0.4f);
}
```

Or this to your parent:

```
void Update ()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < transform.childCount; i++)
    {
        Transform t = transform.GetChild(i);
        t.localPosition += t.localPosition.normalized * Input.GetAxis("Mouse ScrollWheel") * 0.4f;
    }
}
```

Edit:

But if you want them to follow their forward direction use this rather:

```
void Update ()
{
    transform.localPosition += ((transform.localRotation * Vector3.forward) * Input.GetAxis("Mouse ScrollWheel") * 0.4f);
}
```

Comment: Yeah using empty GameObjects to hod the items to fan is the way to go (by changing the empty objects orientation you can change the fanning direction while maintaining the graphical object in any orientation). Also you can use a simple `Mathf.Clamp` to limit the fanning operation.